# url does not work on server but does on localhost

Tags: php, href, require

I got a problem with my page loader, I have a "buttons" function that I have placed in my pagebanner controller (pagebanner.php). It looks like this:

```
<?php
   if(isset($buttons)){
    foreach($buttons as $button) {
        echo "<a href='$button[1]' class='w3-btn w3-dark-gray w3-margin-
left'>$button[0]</a>";
     }
  }
?>
```

When I am making a new file, I require the pagebanner.php So i can make buttons in the new file, Like this:

```
   $buttons = Array(

     ['Inplannen', '/?page=onderhoudInplannen&kid='.$_GET['kid'] 
    .'&id='.$row['id']],
     ['Afboeken', '/?page=onderhoudAfboeken&kid='.$_GET['kid'] 
    .'&id='.$row['id']],
);
```

But the problem is, that it doesn't lead me to that particular page, but I leads my to my default page where I go when the program doesn't recognize the page name. In my url bar it will show me the good url with the good id's but it just doesn't go to the page.

The first link doesn't work, it is on my server:

Link: 192.168.1.9:8000/?page=onderhoudAfboeken&kid=18&id=217

But the second link does work and it is on my localhost:

Link: http://localhost:8000/?page=onderhoudAfboeken&kid=18&id=217

I want the link to work on my server. How can i solve this?
Thanks,

Comment: What happens when you try? "It doesn't work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Are you sure on your server the web server is on port 8000? Usually it's on port 80.

Comment: Your URL begins with a forward slash, meaning that it will target the root of the host-name. Is the application on your server being run from a sub-directory?

Comment: It will lead me to my index.php, this means my system can't find the page with that page name. But I got the page name in my documents with the good path on my server.@aynber

Comment: @AnthonyB Yes it is on port 8000 I did this because port 80 was already occupied

Comment: @YannickGijsbers if your web server is on port 8000 and your application is at the root (not in any subdirectory), your URL is probably right. But in the URL you use some ids, do these ids exist in your database? Otherwise, we'll need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: @AnthonyB Yes they do  exist in my database. And my application is staged in the root, I can teamviewer if you want

Comment: @YannickGijsbers I can teamvierwer in 3 hours if you need to. Before that try to add some logs in your controller to see exactly what happens.

Comment: Is url rewriting enabled? Does this link work?  http://localhost:8000/?page.php=onderhoudAfboeken&kid=18&id=217

Comment: @serialworm I think it has its localhost and in the same network an other PC, Raspberry or anything else that he's calling "server". So if he type localhost:8000 it will find it's own version of the application, not the one of the server.

Comment: @serialworm that link does not work :(

Comment: @AnthonyB With "server" I mean a Cisco machine with QNAP software also called a "NAS"

Comment: @YannickGijsbers Ok, so `192.168.1.9` is the address of the NAS on your network I guess. On your server, all the application doesn't work, or only this page?

Comment: @AnthonyB Hey Anthony I fxixed the issue :D! It's because the NAS is LINUX based and my localhost is on WINDOWS. So I had to make the filenames Lowecase, Cause LINUX is Lower case sensitive (lol)

Comment: @YannickGijsbers It was in an include or something like that? Ok so the problem is solved, but as you can see we hadn't enough informations to solve it. The next time please add more explanations and/or code.

Comment: @AnthonyB Yes my file name was camelCase, but when I pushed my file to the NAS it couldn't read my file when I pressed the button cause it was still camelCase. I had to change the filename to lower case so the NAS could read the file. Thanks for the help and next time I will implement more explanation, sorry for that!

Comment: @YannickGijsbers OSX has the same _problem_, it can be very weird. A question with good explanation and example has a better answer. But for now you probably should add an answer yourself and accept it, so it someone else has the same problem as yours it will find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your server isn't a Linux machine, if it is a Linux machine you have to make all your URL's lowercase. Otherwise your Linux server won't find them.